# The value got in multiplication showing some difference

Tags: reactjs

```
this.props.credit = '4.10';
 let rate = this.props.credit*100;
```

I used all **parseFloat** and **Number** types along with credit. But the result is always getting as 409.99999999999994. But we know actually the value is 410. Why is  getting point difference in reactjs

Comment: I think this will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014

Answer (score 0):

This is how javascript behaves and yes it is sometimes quite strange.

You can read more here for example:
https://medium.com/@DominicCarmel/understanding-javascripts-weird-decimal-calculations-e65f0e1adefb

Answer (score 0):

```js
let credit = '4.10';
 let rate =parseFloat(credit*100).toFixed();
 console.log(rate)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).